# Php $var returning no value inside HTML

Tags: php

I have a variable `$success` set to `$success = "Successfully Created"` but the var `$success` has no value inside HTML.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // username and password sent from form

    if (isset($_POST['okbutton'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['clientuser'], $_POST['clientpass'])) {
            $clientuser = $_POST['clientuser'];
            $clientpass = $_POST['clientpass'];

            $_SESSION['cuser'] = $clientuser;
            $_SESSION['cpass'] = $clientpass;

            header('Location: trialaccount.php');
            die();
        }
    }
}
try {
    if (isset($_SESSION['cuser'])) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_id=:username");
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['cuser']);
        $stmt->execute();

        $checkdup = $stmt->rowCount();

        if ($checkdup == 0) {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user (user_id, user_pass, user_online, user_enable, user_start_date, user_end_date, reseller, type) VALUES (:clientuser, :clientpass,0, 1, now(), now() + interval 4 hour, :panelUSER, 'Trial')");

            $stmt->bindParam(':clientuser', $_SESSION['cuser']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':clientpass', $_SESSION['cpass']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':panelUSER', $username);
            $stmt->execute();


            $success =  "Trial Account Created Successfully!";
        } else {
            $error = "Username '" . $_SESSION['cuser'] . "' is already taken. Try to input unique username." ;
        }
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: Database Error";
}
```

Inside my HTML, I use echo!

```
<?php if(isset($success)){ echo $success; } ?>
```

var `$success` is returning the value on my personal smartphone,
but no value on other devices.

I dont know what is happening?
Can I use Session instead? ty

Comment: can you show us some code please? ty

Comment: @Juakali92 post edited ty

Comment: @RyanJonesBayron Are these bits of code in different files? same file?  are you using includes?  Right now, your question is _Off-Topic: Why isn't my code working_ and will be closed because we don't have enough information to isolate the cause of the problem and we have insufficient explanation of the fault (`$success` is empty on all other devices).  Please give us more details and echo the `$error` values and/or temporarily create other `$success` declaration that will have a value to display when things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your method does not get the total row count. Therefore, it doesn't go through (**if($checkdup == 0)**) to set the value for $success. You can try the code below.

**Replace:**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_id=:username");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['cuser']);
$stmt->execute();

$checkdup = $stmt->rowCount();
```

**With:**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE user_id=:username");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['cuser']);
$stmt->execute();

$checkdup = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: I appreciate you answer, but my concern is about the $success variable returning value.

thank you for that info.

Comment: Yeah. That's the fix for it too. Have you tried it?

Comment: nothing's wrong with that, the condition for $checkup is OK. the sql query inside in that condition running smoothly.

but the $success variable is returning no value.